# Remove duplicate strings in specific line

Tags: text-processing

I have a config file in multiple machines which has some duplicated strings in specific line.

```
Option1 value
Option2 value
Option3 value
# Option X value
# commentary lines
... 
AllowList user1@ip1 user1@ip2 user2@ip3 user2@ip4 user1@ip1 user1@ip2 user2@ip3 user2@ip4 ... 
...
Option Z value
```

In `AllowList` line, there are duplicate values. How to get rid of them?

I already know how to remove the duplicate values :

```
grep AllowList myconfig | tr ' ' '\n' | sort | uniq | xargs
```

But I want to do that in place, leaving other lines intact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**`allowlist.awk`**:

```c
/AllowList/{
  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){
    #Check if the field is a repeated in the line, print the field if not.
    if(!a[$i]++){
      printf "%s ",$i
    }
  }
  split("",a) #Equivalent to delete(a)
  print ""    #Print a newline
  next
}
1
```

Execute the Awk script and overwrite original file.

```
awk -f allowlist.awk myconfig > temporary
mv temporary myconfig
```

Answer (score 2):

How about perl, with `uniq` (or `uniqstr`) from `List::util`?

```
$ perl -MList::Util=uniq -alpe '$_ = join " ", uniq @F if $F[0] eq "AllowList"' myconfig
Option1 value
Option2 value
Option3 value
# Option X value
# commentary lines
...
AllowList user1@ip1 user1@ip2 user2@ip3 user2@ip4 ...
...
Option Z value
```

You can add `-i` for in-place operation.

Answer (score -1):

Pick out the relevant line from the file, split it into lines, sort with a uniqueness attribute, join it all together again

```
grep '^AllowList' file | tr ' ' '\n' | LC_ALL=C sort -u | xargs
```

Using your example, this provides the following result

```
AllowList user1@ip1 user1@ip2 user2@ip3 user2@ip4
```

It presupposes that the only "word" on the line starting with a capital letter is the keyword `AllowList`, and it uses this assumption to place it at the beginning of the sorted line.

Comment: That's what I did actually. I'll edit my question.

Comment: Please also explain there why it doesn't work for you

Comment: It does work but the config file will left unchanged.

Comment: Please see my edit

Comment: Of course it's unchanged. You take the output into a new file and then replace the original file. This is Computing 101

Comment: But if OP does that, the resulting file will only contain the (now modified) matching lines, not all the lines.

Comment: @Quasímodo the [original question that I answered](https://unix.stackexchange.com/revisions/610388/1) wrote, "_In AllowList line, there are duplicate values. How to get rid of them?_" and "_I already googled on this but what I could find is how to remove duplicate lines, not what I'm looking for._" The implication being that they knew - or had learned - how to edit the file. It also did not say, "_I already know how to remove the duplicate values_"